# Import large(1.5GB) XML to Excel

Tags: xml, excel

I have 1.5gb(19 million lines) XML file which I need to compare with some of my excel reports. I tried import XML in Excel 365 but I keep getting error messages like "not enough memory to complete this action" . I have 12GB RAM so I think that my HW should be able to handle it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Luckily some people are more helpful and experienced than you. It turns out that everything that was needed was Excel 2016 with PowerPivot. So yes it is definitely possible ;)

Comment: I pointed you to Power Pivot as an option, but with a caveat that it may still not work. Sorry that I could not test your specific scenario, but you did not share your 1.5 GB file for testing. At this point in time, Excel 2016 has not yet been released and is only available as a preview. If you are happy to put your eggs into that basket, go for it. I've been around the block a few times and I've seen things go wrong even after public releases. Hence my vote for caution. Feel free to ridicule.

Comment: I never said it was not possible. I am advising caution to push the system to the max. Power Pivot will be instrumental and I have advised you to use Power Pivot in my answer below, but even Power Pivot for Excel has limits. Using SQL as a source opens up much bigger data scenarios than using only Excel. Yes, it may work. If so, consider yourself lucky. Just don't EXPECT that 19 million rows in Power Pivot will just work. There are a few other parameters that will make a difference. Don't shoot me because I am cautious. I gave your the answer. Power Pivot. Be kind and acknowledge that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that Excel can handle "only" 1,048,576 rows of data?

Even though the Data Model with Power Pivot can handle a lot more, 19 million rows is really pushing the limits. With that much data, you would want the 64 bit version and as much memory as you can afford. Memory and file size will not match one to one. Excel will need a lot more memory than the file size to handle the data.

With that many rows, you are probably beyond what Excel can handle. If a 64 bit version cannot open your data, you will need to use a data base like SQL or similar, which have been designed for large data sets.

Excel was NOT designed for handling 19 million rows, so don't be surprised if it spits the dummy.

Comment: However, XML lines might not match to rows. Each column (node) value could rest on one line. Nonetheless, as you point out with memory resources, the OP needs a database solution (MS Access, SQLite, MySQL, etc.)